# Basic Set Theory Question about Complements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I found this exercise in a set-theory textbook that I'm not sure the answer to. It is not for homework as I don't even go to school any more.

$S - T = \overline{\overline{S} \ \backslash \  \overline{T}}$

It seems to me that this is straightforwardly false, given that complementation is always relative to a background universe of discourse (after all, naive set-theory is inconsistent).

For example, consider:

$\bullet$ The universe $U = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$

$\bullet$ Consider $S = \{a,b,c\}$ and $T = \{a\}$.

Then here is a case in which the alleged identity fails.

This is because $S - T = \{b,c\}$ and yet $\overline{\overline{S} \ \backslash \  \overline{T}} = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your counterexample works.

$$\bar{S} = \{ d, e\}$$

$$\bar{T}=\{ b,c,d,e\}$$

$$\bar{S} \setminus \bar{T} = \emptyset$$ and your conclusion is correct.